# Can't connect target emulator in webOS TV

Tags: eclipse, television, webos, lg

I have installed sdk with ide for webOS TV. I have installed emulator and run it before running webOS TV IDE. However doesn't matter how I try I can't connect to emulator devices. I have the following error: [image]

Answer (score 1):

First, you must run the .vbox file (LG_webOS_TV_Emulator) from Emulator installed directory folder.

If you are using windows OS for example, directory

> C:webOS_TV_SDK\Emulator\v3.00\ (.vbox) file

then you can connect to emulator

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem, cannot connect the emulator into the IDE. So I've tried to skip this step.

First I've exported my project into .ipk file and then using the "menu" button on the emulated remote control, installed it directly via "App Manager". App was working fine this way.

Funnily enough, after this "workaround" the connection error was somehow fixed within the IDE.